# Is there a way in google cloud to block attempt to access specific urls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, firewall, server-side-attacks, google-cloud-armor

I have a VM instance that receives a lot of spam/bot traffic attempting to hack the instance such as `New Request to /blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml`. Although none of these are successful it adds strain to the instance.

Is it possible to block specific endpoint attempts on a google cloud network?

So far I can only find a way to block specific Ip addresses using the firewall.

I'm looking for something similar to the answer here: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-wp-path-probing/204761

Comment: Welcome to hosting a public server. This sort of garbage traffic is normal, and you must plan accordingly. If you are running WordPress, then install a WordPress specific firewall to block these users. There are dozens/hundreds of frameworks. Hackers try many of them. Consider @Serhii answer about Cloud Armor. However, Apache/Nginx can handle not found errors effortlessly. You will either pay for frontends/WAFs to block the traffic or on your backend. There is no free lunch for public-facing servers.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Cloud Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) works on the *Level 3* [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), HTTP/HTTPS works on the *Level 7* OSI model. As a result, you won't be able to use Google Cloud Firewall in this case.

**As a solution** you can use [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall) (WAF) which works on the Level 7 OSI model. Google Cloud Platform provides WAF as a service: [Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor).

Please have a look at the documentation [About Google Cloud Armor security policies](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview#about):

> by using the Google Cloud Armor custom rules language reference, **you
> can create custom conditions that match on various attributes of the
> incoming traffic**, **such as the URL path**, request method, or request
> header values.

and at the section [Allow or deny traffic for a request URI that matches a regular expression](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#allow_or_deny_traffic_for_a_request_uri_that_matches_a_regular_expression):

> The following expression matches with requests that contain the string
> bad_path in the URI:
>
> `request.path.matches('/bad_path/')`